# Computing the Wasserstein $1$-Distance of the distribution $P_{0} \sim (0, Z)$ for $Z \sim U[0,1]$ and $P_{\theta} := (\theta, Z)$.

Tags: probability-theory, wasserstein

In reading about Wasserstein GANS [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875), an example is given in the middle of page $4$.

Let $Z \sim U [0,1]$, and let $P_0 \sim [0,Z] \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $P_{\theta} := (\theta, Z)$ be a probability distribution parametrized by a constant $\theta$.

The following identity is stated but not argued:

- The Wasserstein $1$-distance (also referred to as the Earth Mover's Distance) $W$ between $P_0$ and $P_\theta$ satisfies $W(P_0, P_\theta) = | \theta|$

For the Wasserstein $1$-distance, I am accustomed to using this metric for probability distributions of one variable, so in this case I think (not sure) that  $$W(P_0, P_\theta) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Pi  (P_0, P_{\theta} )}\int_{x \in X} \int_{x' \in X'} \int_{y \in Y} \int_{y' \in Y'}\|(x,y) -(x', y')\| \gamma(x,y, x', y')\,\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}x' \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}y'$$ where $\Pi(P_0, P_{\theta} )$ is the set of joint distributions of $(x,y)$ with marginals equal to $P_0$ and $P_{\theta}$.

Consider two cases. If $\theta = 0$, then the distributions are equal and the distance is $0$. Now suppose that $\theta \neq 0$, it seems the first step to compute the desired integral is to reason what is $\inf_{\gamma \in \Pi  (P_0, P_{\theta} )} $?

Since the first co-ordinate of both distributions is constant for $(x,y)$ pairs with non-zero support, then it seems like $\gamma(x, y, x', y')$ has two cases. If $x=0, x'= \theta$, then for $(y,y') \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ we have $\gamma(x,y,x',y') = 1$, and $\gamma$ is zero otherwise.

How to use the above to show that $W(P_0, P_\theta) = |\theta|$ eludes me, any insights appreciated.

Comment: You've introduced $n$ from nowhere! Anyway the point is that a bit of earth starting at $\left(0,y\right)$ needs to end up at $\left(\theta,y\right)$. So it's all getting moved exactly distance $\lvert \theta\rvert$.

Comment: @Ali right I was tired sorry, I meant its the product of two uniform pdfs on the interval $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ which I guess is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the notation a bit we note that $W(P_0,P_\theta)$ is given by $\inf\mathbb{E}[\|(0,Z)-(\theta,Z')\|]$, where the infimum is taken over all distributions of $(Z,Z')$ such that the marginals are $U(0,1)$-distributed. Regardless of the joint distribution of $(Z,Z')$ it holds that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\|(0,Z)-(\theta,Z')\|]\geq\mathbb{E}[\|(0,Z)-(\theta,Z)\|].
$$
This shows that the infimum is attained at the joint distribution $(Z,Z')\sim(Z,Z)$. Hence,
$$
W(P_0,P_\theta)=\mathbb{E}[\|(0,Z)-(\theta,Z)\|]=|\theta|.
$$

Comment: How did you get that first inequality? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can write $\|(0,Z)-(\theta,Z’)\|^2=\theta^2+(Z-Z’)^2\geq\theta^2=\|(0,Z)-(\theta,Z)\|$

Comment: @IntegrateThis I think the point is that the distance between two points (0, x) and (0, x') is at its minimum when x = x'. So you can pick Z' = Z (note how the 2D distribution then collapses to a line)